# Passing Users between Twilio Studio Flows

Tags: twilio

Hi im relatively new to Twilio, and love Twilio Studio.
However, Can someone clarify whether this is possible.

I have built a simple Welcome flow in studio receiving SMS messages no problem. An Autopilot widget processes the incoming messages to which i then send the reply to a specific Flow in Studio.

This all works amazingly well...until the user is in this specific Flow (let's say Flow A). Once in this Flow A, at some point I ask for input to redirect to another Flow B.

But when I test the response (via a Send and Wait for Reply widget) to get to Flow B (using a redirect) nothing happens.

Can Twilio not process or pass users between different Flows from SMS (or any messaging app)?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Studio does not currently support passing users between flows. Currently the best thing to do is include all of your flow logic within the one flow and make decisions using the split widget.

Comment: While researching this I came across [TwiML Redirect widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/twiml-redirect) that enables to redirect away from studio to execute custom TwiML.@philnash Would it be possible to use this for redirecting from one flow to another.

Comment: @TumainiMosha to be honest, I haven’t tried that. You’re welcome to try it yourself, though I’d worry that the Execution for the first flow would appear stuck. Studio does work best if everything is in the same flow.